# Proper way to set up a download daemon, regarding permissions

Tags: linux, security, permissions

I am a Linux novice, and I am setting up a single board computer to use for downloading files, among other things. I have installed aria2 download utility for that purpose.

What is the proper way to set up such a service, regarding basic security and permissions?

This is what I came up with:

1. It is my understanding that the general consensus regarding external facing services is to create a separate user account for them. So I created a "system" user for it with `/usr/sbin/nologin` as its shell.
2. aria2 likes to store it's configuration files in a home directory, so I created a home for it in the `/home/aria2` directory.
3. Finally, the service will be used by several users who all should have access to the downloaded files. So I created a separate directory in `/srv` to store downloaded files and I assigned it to `download` group. I added aria2 user and these users to the `download` group.

I am interested if this is sound approach, and if not why?

The specific question is about aria2, but I believe that the general guidelines applies to other software.

Comment: "aria2 likes to store it's configuration files in a home directory". This breaks Unix principles. The place for configuration files in Unix systems is `/etc`.

Comment: What's a single board computer?  In my mind's eye, this calls up a picture of a 2x4 with mobo and stuff screwed onto it. (Not that there's anything wrong with DIY).

Comment: I am using a cubieboard2, take a look here - http://cubieboard.org/model/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General guidelines are for instance the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)

> It is my understanding that the general consensus regarding external facing services is to create a separate user account for them. So I created a "system" user for it with /usr/sbin/nologin as its shell.

Yep, nothing wrong with that.

> aria2 likes to store it's configuration files in a home directory, so I created a home for it in the /home/aria2 directory.

Convention for services/daemons is to store their configuration in `/etc/`, a single config file maybe as `/etc/<application>.conf` and a set of configuration files in an application specific subdirectory such as for instance `/etc/<application>/`

A second convention is that only users have their home directory in `/home/`,  and system accounts elsewhere, somewhere under `/var/` is common but other locations may be equally suitable.